# Change SetParameters.xml in Web Deploy

Tags: xml, web-config, web-deployment, msdeploy

How can I add and set a parameter at the same time in the SetParameters.xml file to change an app setting?

I have tried below to change the app setting key `BaseURL` but it's not changing the value when deployed using `msdeploy`. Is there something I am missing?

```
<parameters>
<setParameter name="BaseURL" kind="XmlFile" scope="\\web.config$" match="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='BaseURL']/@value" value="http://test-mvc/api/" />
</parameters>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include `setParameter` elements and `parameter` elements side by side, just use `defaultValue` to set the value:

```
<parameters>
  <setParameter name="OtherParam" value="false" />

  <parameter name="BaseURL" defaultValue="http://test-mvc/api/">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="Web\.config$" 
                    match="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='BaseURL']/@value" />
  </parameter>
</parameter>
```